# infinite loop for checking aws instance status in ec2 targetgroup while draining

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, do-while

I am trying to capture the status of an ec2 instance which is part of a target group. I try to de-register the instance and then inside a do until look I constantly check for the status of the instance when it migrates from `draining` to `unused` and then exit out of the loop at that point. I am unable to figure out why it is getting into an infinite loop even though I constantly check for the status. Here is the power-shell snippet I am using

```
       $instance_id = "i-ec2ID"
       $targetGroupArn = "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:region:accountID:targetgroup/tg-name/guid12345"
       aws elbv2 deregister-targets --target-group-arn $targetGroupArn --targets Id=$instance_id
       
       Do {
            
            $instance_status = aws elbv2 describe-target-health --target-group-arn $targetGroupArn --query "TargetHealthDescriptions[].{Id:Target.Id,Health:TargetHealth.State}" --output text|Select-String -Pattern $instance_id
            $a = $instance_status.ToString()
            $instance_state = $a.Substring(0, $a.Length - 20)
            echo "Instance is still: "$instance_state
            Start-Sleep -s 10
        }
        Until ($instance_state -match "unused")
```

Any suggestion on how to overcome this issue or any better suggestion to achieve what I am trying to do is welcome

Comment: Are you sure `$instance_status.ToString() = aws elbv2 ...` within the loop actually updates $instace_status value?

Comment: ideally it captures the output of an aws cli command in string format and the `Do` statement should run it every-time the loop iterates. But it looks like it does not else there would have been a transition in the status of the ec2 instance. Any suggestion on how the infinite loop can be avoided?

Comment: So why does the first one outside of the loop look like `$instance_status = aws elbv2... ` and the one in the loop like `$instance_status.ToString() = aws elbv2 ...`? What's the reason for the `.ToString()` there?

Comment: I have updated the original post. I should have removed from the original post. It was to capture the output in string format which will be used in further manipulation. Also I tried to this `Until ($instance_state -match $null) `  and when I do that it runs the loop only once and exits even though the instance is still draining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue and was able to resolve it by putting an `if-else` block inside the `do until` loop which will basically evaluate the status if it is null and exit out of the loop gracefully

```
   Do {
        
        $instance_status = aws elbv2 describe-target-health --target-group-arn $targetGroupArn --query "TargetHealthDescriptions[].{Id:Target.Id,Health:TargetHealth.State}" --output text|Select-String -Pattern $instance_id
        if($instance_status -eq $null) {
            $instance_state = $null
        }
        else{
            $a = $instance_status.ToString()
            $instance_state = $a.Substring(0, $a.Length - 20)
            echo "Instance is still: "$instance_state
            Start-Sleep -s 10
        }

    }
    Until ($instance_state -eq $null)
```

Hopefully this helps someone